# Dynamic Job Schedule in SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL job that I have been trying to configure to run between a certain time (4pm - 7pm). 
I created the job I want to run between this time (lets call it DynJob). I set it a default schedule with the days I want it to run, and a default time value of 4pm.

But I don't want it to run at 4pm every single time it runs. 
I want it to run between 4pm - 7pm.

So I created another job (SJob). This job runs at 2pm (2 hours earlier than the scheduled start time for DynJob). All SJob does is run a query against the dbo.sysjobschedules, and does some math to come up with a value somewhere between 160000 and 190000, and inserts that value into the next_run_time field where the schedule_id = DynJob's schedule ID.

And it works (not really). It will adjust the time in the table, and I can see it gets a value (lets say 175691). But, it's all for not. Because when 4pm comes around, DynJob still gets run. Then SQL sets DynJobs next_run_time back to 4pm (160000) after it has run.

Am I going at this all wrong? **Is there an easier way to set a job schedule for a window of time instead of one static time?**

Here is the TSQL I am using that I talked about above.

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @CallTime int = 1
DECLARE @MaxTime int = 30000
SET @CallTime = @MaxTime*RAND() + 160000

UPDATE dbo.sysjobschedules
SET next_run_time = @CallTime
WHERE schedule_id = 1
```

As always, thanks for taking the time!

P.S. Yes, I know having 2 jobs and 2 schedules just to get this to work is silly, but I am a newb and know not the ways of SQL Server Agent :) So any answers, or helpful documentation is always appreciated! If this is dumb, tell me! But explain it as well

Comment: You will need to set a Frequency and/or Duration depending on your job.  (Does it run for several hours, or run multiple times between hours A and B?)  [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.120).aspx) has some good information.

Comment: No, it will run once between A and B, but it will run 5 days a week. I just want the time between A and B to be random.

Comment: There's no feature for a random start time.  (DBA's generally don't like having tasks start at random times.  It's not something I would expect to see.)  So I guess the question becomes *why* do you need the SQL Agent to generate a random start time?   (Perhaps SQL Agent is the wrong tool or perhaps there is a better way to achieve your end goal.)

Comment: I need to send files to a ftp server at a random time. As soon as the files get to that server, a process takes the information and does "x" with that info. But "x" cannot happen at the same time every day, or the process will be overall less effective (Can't divulge more then that). I have no control after the files are sent to the ftp server. So I must make sure that the files are sent exactly when I intend to do "x". Since "x" needs to happen at a random time between 4-7, I have to schedule it justly. If it were up to me, I would use an executable, but I MUST use an SSIS package for this.

Comment: Wow, interesting set of requirements.  Very unusual.  Regardless, I think your original idea is probably on the right track.  If changing the next start time in sysjobschedules is not working just right, how about adjusting your 2nd job so that instead of changing the start time you drop or detach the schedule and add/attach a completely new schedule to the 1st job?  Maybe that will fix whatever issues you're having with your current technique.  (You didn't specify why it isn't working.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution in the [sp_update_schedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187354.aspx) stored procedure. Using one job which runs this stored procedure to generate and update schedules of other jobs, I got this to work.

The only tricky part is making sure you are getting the correct time configured, and you are using the right permissions in the job running the sp_update_schedule procedure...

> "Only members of sysadmin can modify a schedule owned by another user."